# Android calculate bitmap inSampleSize to different target size

Tags: android, size, measure

First I have a custom component, which is show pictures from the web. It's a simple layout and include a circle progressbar and an ImageView. In the default state the progressbar is visible and it's showing while picture downloading and when it's finished I hide the progressbar and show the picture in the ImageView. It's working very well, but int he emulator and on HTC Hero I got [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget](http://www.google.hu/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError%3A+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget) error. I found the  [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503628/bitmapfactory-decodestream-returning-null-when-options-are-set). But my problem, that the TARGET_WIDTH and TARGET_HEIGHT not fix, sometimes 60x90, sometimes fill_parent x fill_parent, and I can't calculate this values in the decode function.
For example I added my view in the xml with layout_width="fill_parent" and use in Activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ImageLoader picture = (ImageLoader) findViewById(R.id.picture);
picture.load("http://winportal.net/images/galleries/wallpapers/Earth.jpg");
```

and in the load method I call the decode function from the solution and try here calculate sizes:

```
...
this.onMeasure(0, 0);
Log.d("Log", "Layout width: " + this.getMeasuredWidth());

TARGET_WIDTH =  this.getMeasuredWidth();
...
```

and the result is: "*Layout width: 24*"

I don't understand why got 24 bacause is the width of progressbar, but the layout - which is include it - is fill_parent width. I tried override onMeasure method but got 0.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
}
```

I tried override onSizeChanged too. It's give good values but it's run later, after decode :(

How can I calculate my layout size?

Answer (score 0):

When you call "this.onMeasure(0, 0);" you force the view to do measurements with following rules - [UNSPECIFIED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#UNSPECIFIED). Your view have following state: ProgressBar is visible, ImageView is hidden, so the result will be 24.

At the beginning, try to use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) with ProgressBar and ImageView. In that scenario you don't have to care about measurements. Just only make sure that the image is no too big ( in case of OutOfMemory). You can download image file to temporary file, than check the size with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds), calculate appropriate sampling size and do decode, set bitmap for ImageView, set scale [type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for ImageView.