# Efficient retrieval of scaled asset bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, assets

I've got a `GridView` of many images which are retrieved from the assets folder and decoded from streams. These are typically quite large (to be used elsewhere in the app), but for the GridView need to only be 140dp wide or have a minimum height of 150dp. Which of the options in `BitmapFactory.Options` should I use to scale the image to this density/resolution? I'm confused by the many different density options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fast retrieval, you should use [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize). It automatically loads a smaller bitmap without first loading the full image into memory.

Comment: The issue with this is that I don't know which sample size to use; all the files are of significantly different sizes

Comment: You can read the image sizes without loading a full image as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503628/bitmapfactory-decodestream-returning-null-when-options-are-set/2528718#2528718