# Out of memory error in android bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am using a bitmap. It throws out of memory error (2 out of 5 times).
How can it be avoided.

**Following is my code**:

```
  bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
  photo_new= rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  photo_new.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),new_class.class);
  i.putExtra("image", byteArray);

  startActivity(i);
  byteArray=null;
```

Comment: It works fine on different images? What are the differences. And at which point it throws memory error?

Comment: Whats the size of those bitmaps?

Comment: it is throwing error on:
`bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting [OutOfMemoryError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) because you haven't `recycle`
those `bitmaps` you used

try to `recycle` those `bitmaps` after you used them

```
bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
  photo_new= rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  photo_new.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
  bitmap.recycle();
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),new_class.class);
  i.putExtra("image", byteArray);

  startActivity(i);
  byteArray=null;
```

Comment: Am using the above code without any modification, but unfortunately first line itself giving me OutOffMemory error.

MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri); //in this line it is crashed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381113/mediastore-images-media-getbitmap-and-out-of-memory-error @AnbarasuChinna

Answer (score 3):

```
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

in that line your ram is getting filled by whole Bitmap. Change bitmap quality from 100 to `50-60` as below

```
 photo_new.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
```

or

```
 photo_new.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
```

try both and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

## wrong

1). Bitmap quality is high.

2). you are not using try catch.

## Suggestions

1). reduce the quality of bitmap to 45-50.

2). use try catch block to prevent your app from crash.

## Solution // sender activity

```
try{
     Intent _intent = new Intent(this, newscreen.class);
     Bitmap _bitmap; // your bitmap
     ByteArrayOutputStream _bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     _bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, _bs);
     i.putExtra("byteArray", _bs.toByteArray());
     startActivity(i);
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

## receiver activity

```
try{
     if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

     ImageView _imv= new ImageView(this);
     Bitmap _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);        
    _imv.setImageBitmap(_bitmap);
 }
}catch(Exception e){
 }
```