# OutOfMemory Error Android:

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am try to converting image to bitmap using following bit of code:

```
//Here file is the image file
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Now the problem is some times i got the `OutOfMemoryError`. I don't know when the error exactly happened.

My simple solution add try catch add and avoid crash. I know it is not the right way.

How to handle `OutOfMemoryError` here?

Comment: ran out of memory. Scale down the image

Comment: You can try to play around with the BitmapFactory.Options. But it is possible that the file is too big to load in memory as a Bitmap.

Comment: you can take a look at [Out of memory error in android bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203985/out-of-memory-error-in-android-bitmap/24204533#24204533)

Comment: @Raghunandan How to do scaling?

Comment: @Joris yes i am handling big files so how to avoid this

Comment: search google stack overflow

Comment: @Amsheer did you read the documentation for BitmapFactory.Options? As is also statedx in the answer there is a field inSampleSize with the description "If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory."

Comment: I mean i am also use decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){} method is it what you mean? In some other place

Answer (score 0):

Add this options in decode in order to optimize memory:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
bmOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
```

Comment: Here also decoding the file. How can you say outofmemory not occur.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPurgeable