# Bitmap image is null after resize

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to resize a picture selected from the SD card to a thumbnail size but when I resize it, to the dimensions on my default image `128/128` the bitmap is null

```
InputStream input=null;
            try {
                input = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)));
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
                int height = options.outHeight; //1030
                int width = options.outWidth; //1033
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_contact_picture, options);

                int imageHeight = options.outHeight; //128
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth; //128


                if(imageWidth > imageHeight){
                    options.inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height/(float)imageHeight);
                }else{
                    options.inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width/(float)imageWidth);
                }
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,null, options); //null here
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                image.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I can get both of the images height and width but when I go to resize it, it returns a null bitmap.

I have done it this way with resource files but never with a `Uri` of an image from the SD card so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same input stream twice, so you will need to create a new InputStream the second time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503628/bitmapfactory-decodestream-returning-null-when-options-are-set) for more info.

Comment: ahh did not know that, that was the reason